# how to find where homebrew temporarily saves dependencies being downloaded

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm installing `wkhtmltopdf` on my Mac using `homebrew install wkhtmltopdf` so it would go on like this: `Installing wkhtmltopdf dependency: qt`. 
For some reason, my internet connection causes the download of a 200+mb file (`Downloading http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5.tar.gz`) to only go at 4KB/s so I just copied my friend's version of the tar file.
My OS version is Mavericks and QT does not support it yet so installing it separately will not work (already tried it).

How would I be able to just copy the tar file and place it wherever brew stores temporary files or whatsoever, so that brew won't need to download it anymore? Specifically, where can I place the `tar.gz` file?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Homebrew stores downloaded files in either `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew` or `/Library/Caches/Homebrew` (the former if it exists and the latter if the former doesn't). If you've already used Homebrew, check those locations and see which one exists, and drop the tar file you downloaded in that directory.

Comment: copied the file at `/Library/Caches/Homebrew` and brew recognized the file. big thanks for your help @mipadi!